# Spring MongoDB @Query parameter ?0 not being substituted

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am using the Spring/MongoDB @Query annotation as follows with @EnableMongoRepositories specified, but the String parameter substitution causes a parsing/number format exception. When I hardcode a String date for debugging purposes, it works. Am I missing a dependency or something to get this to work. Here are the relevant sections:

This works:

```
@Query("{'MyData.fromDatestamp' : { $gte: { $numberLong: \"20130801000000\" } }}")
List<MyData> findMyData();
```

This does not:

```
@Query("{'MyData.fromDatestamp' : { $gte: { $numberLong: ?0 } }}")
List<MyData> findMyData(String fromDatestamp);
```

The error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "_param_0"
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
}
```

...

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb")
compile("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.2.2")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.0")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0")
```

And here is my config:

```
@Configuration public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return databaseName;
}

@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient(dataStoreHost,dataStorePort);
}

@Override
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return mongoClient();
}

@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient(), databaseName);
}

@Override
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

}

Also, I have tried these variations which fail with JSONParseException:

```
@Query("{'MyData..fromDatestamp' : { $gte: { $numberLong: \"?0\" } }}")

@Query("{'MyData..fromDatestamp' : { $gte: { $numberLong: '?0' } }}")
```

Thanks in advance for any insight or thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the type to long, and it worked. I had tried changing from String to long in an earlier test, but I think maybe I had $numberLong specified in the query json when it wasn't needed. Although it shows NumberLong in Mongo console for my date field, this finally worked for the query. Note that I had also added the @Repository annotation to the top of my interface:

```
@Query(value = "{MyData.fromDatestamp : { $gte: ?0 } }")
List<MyData> findMyData(long fromDatestamp);
```